# Crystal Report Connection Failed After Refresh Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I have build an Report application using C# and Crystal Report
I build program with Formula Selection to Change Query when User need to Filter the report.
The program build in Windows 7.
In the windows 7 program is running well as I needed, data and anything  is shown like I needed.
But I need to run in Windows XP.
I try to filter date into to day.

The problem is on CrystalReportViewer RefreshReport();
If I don't use that function data on report doesn't refresh, but if I use that function The connection failed to logon
Here is the code:

```
skr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
dp = new DailyParking();
dp.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "passwd", "host", "dbname");
repotviewer.ReportSource = dp;            
repotviewer.SelectionFormula = "Date({transaksi1.masuk})=Date('" +skr+ "') ";
repotviewer.RefreshReport();
repotviewer.Refresh();
```

Comment: What is the need to refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, Install the Another MySql Connector which compatible in XP, after that create the connection in MyODBC.

Change The code like here:

```
skr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
dp = new DailyParking();
dp.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "passwd", "host", "dbname");
dp.RecordSelectionFormula = "Date({transaksi1.masuk}) = Date('" + skr + "') ";
repotviewer.ReportSource = dp;
repotviewer.Refresh();
```

Change the MySQL.Data reference with new MySQL connector same with installed in XP  and Rebuil Program.